# How can I build a cheap, do-it-yourself dance floor?

Tags: floor, flooring, linoleum

I would like to make a cheap DIY dance floor and I attained a roll of 3.5 ft x 6 ft vinyl linoleum for free.  Can I use this in making a dance floor?  Has anyone built their own cheap DIY and what materials did they use?  Has anyone failed at doing this and what should I avoid?  Are there any good guides to doing this on the internet?

Comment: What is the original surface that will support the dance floor? Is it supposed to be temporary (removable) or permanent?

Comment: It should be a removable floor.  There are a few of my friends interested in the question in general (for a cheap diy floor without the free linoleum) and they will have different floors.  Some suggestions for a carpet would be great.  If you have suggestions for different floors please share those as well.

Comment: What type of dancing?

Comment: @Tester101, I'm curious why that matters.  I guess it it was riverdancing or stomp it would be tougher on the floor.  Anyways, we will be doing salsa, lindy hop, and blues.

Comment: @Tester101 I stand corrected about the type of dance mattering.  This site has a table of the floor you need based on the type of dance: http://stagestep.com/floortools_styleuse.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an [article](http://www.ehow.com/how_6003507_make-temporary-dance-floor.html) ([How to Make a Temporary Dance Floor](http://www.ehow.com/how_6003507_make-temporary-dance-floor.html)) on how to make a dance floor from [Medium-density fiberboard (MDF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium-density_fibreboard) and some old scrap carpeting.  Home Depot also sells carpeting by the roll and it is pretty inexpensive (then you could get just the right size fit for the MDF boards and also the area of your dance floor).

> Purchase MDF and scrap carpet at a
>   hardware store specific to your
>   measurements. Standard MDF will be 3/4
>   inch thick and will be cut into 4 feet
>   by 8 feet pieces. You should have the
>   MDF cut into pieces that will fit
>   easily into your space. Purchase the
>   same amount of scrap carpet to place
>   underneath the MDF.
>
> Glue the scrap carpet to the underside
>   of the MDF. This will prevent your
>   floor from being scratched and will
>   provide cushioning for your feet and
>   knees.

Comment: Great link, thanks. Would upvote you but I don't have the ability yet.

Answer (score 4):

Would a bamboo rug work?

[image]

It'd be easy to roll up when not in use. I don't know if it's a great dancing surface, though.

Comment: This may just work with the linoleum.  I would upvote you but I don't have enough points yet.  I will look more into this.